# Centering a JButton using Box Layout.X_AXIS

Tags: java, swing, centering, boxlayout

I have a JPanel that can have either 1 or 2 buttons, depending on what's going on in the program at the time. I'm using Box Layout.X_AXIS to line up the 2 buttons configuration, and it works great. When I switch to 1 button however, the single button is on the far left of the window. I've tried a bunch of different things to get the button centered, but the only thing that seems to work is this:

```
JButton yesBtn = new JButton("Continue");
btnPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btnPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
yesBtn.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

The problem with this is that the vertical location of the button changes doing it this way, so it doesn't match where the 2 buttons would sit vertically. Is there a way to center the button using the X_AXIS layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried a bunch of different things to get the button centered,

The easiest way is to add `"glue"` BEFORE the first component and AFTER the last component. Then it will work for 1 component or multiple components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Invisible Components as Filler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) for more information and examples.